# Swift link Image from Parse array using segues to secondViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, segue

Here is my code, i am trying to use the "prepareForSegue" function to send an image from tableViewController (firstViewController) to my detailedViewController (secondViewController). I have managed to populate my firstViewController from the parse cloud successfully and I have managed to get my secondViewController Labels to update, but i can not get the imageView to update. I have posted my code below

firstViewController

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:      AnyObject?) {

    let eventDetailVC: EventDetailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as!  EventDetailsVC
    if let selectedArrayIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {

        eventDetailVC.detailNameLabel = postedEvents[selectedArrayIndex]
        eventDetailVC.detailAddressLabel = postedAddress[selectedArrayIndex]
        eventDetailVC.detailCityLabel = postedCity[selectedArrayIndex]
        eventDetailVC.detailStateLabel = postedState[selectedArrayIndex]
        eventDetailVC.detailStartLabel = postedStart[selectedArrayIndex]
        eventDetailVC.detailEndLabel = postedEnd[selectedArrayIndex]
        eventDetailVC.detailPriceLabel = postedPrices[selectedArrayIndex]
        eventDetailVC.detailDescriptionLabel =    postedDescription[selectedArrayIndex]

        // The error is here....i think
        eventDetailVC.detailImageView.image = image

    }
}
```

secondViewController

```
   var detailNameLabel = String()
   var detailDescriptionLabel = String()
   var detailPriceLabel = String()
   var detailStartLabel = String()
   var detailEndLabel = String()
   var detailAddressLabel = String()
   var detailCityLabel = String()
   var detailStateLabel = String()
   var detailImageView = UIImage()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    detailName.text = detailNameLabel
    detailDescription.text = detailDescriptionLabel
    detailPrice.text = detailPriceLabel
    detailStart.text = detailStartLabel
    detailEnd.text = detailEndLabel
    detailAddress.text = detailAddressLabel
    detailCity.text = detailCityLabel
    detailState.text = detailStateLabel

    // its this line below....i think
    detailImage.image = detailImageView
    }
```

Please can someone help me figure this out, Im kinda new to this whole thing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should define a UIImageView instead of a UIImage in secondViewController. Your `detailImageView` will need to be of type `UIImageView`. The way you have it written, it is of type `UIImage`.

In secondViewController, replace

```
var detailImageView = UIImage()
```

with

```
var detailImageView = UIImageView()
```

Then change:

```
// its this line below....i think
detailImage.image = detailImageView
```

to

```
// its this line below....i think
detailImage.image = detailImageView.image
```

To handle the image sending from the table view cell to the second view controller will require grabbing the image from the selected cell. This would look something like this in your prepareForSegue:

```
if let myIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow? {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(myIndexPath)
    eventDetailVC.detailImageView.image = cell.postedEventImage.image 
}
```

---

Your other assignments in viewDidLoad in secondViewController are also a bit unusual. You appear to be assigning the text values from UILabels based on how you are naming them. If a variable is a UILabel than having it named *something*Label is appropriate. However, if the type is a String, which they are based on your variable assignments, than having it named *something*Label can be a source of confusion.

Comment: i still get an error, i posted my new code for the firstviewController

Comment: Does the image already appear in your table view? If so, you should grab the image from the table view cell *and not from the server again.* Why don't you save the image in the `postImages` array like you are saving the rest of your data? You may not want to because of memory usage. The problem with downloading the image in `prepareForSegue` is that it is a background operation and the image is not immediately available.

Comment: yes the image appears in my table view controller. How do i grab it from the cell and not the server? My postImages array is of type PFFile. what would the code look like?

Comment: I've added a way of retrieving the image from the table view cell in your prepareForSegue. Since you are saying the image is already loaded, you should be able to transfer it to your detail view.

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work, i am so confused i have tried so many things but cant seem to get it work. Any last suggestions?

Comment: You could post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method along with how you are loading the image into `postImages`. The other possibility is that your image view is not configured correctly on your second view controller. Either the image is not getting to your second view controller or the image cannot be seen for some reason. Those are the possibilities and that's what you can focus on to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok well i updated my answer with a little but more code. Thank you for all your help. Seriously once this part is done my app is finished. I have been working on this part for last 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Hers the save code i think you wanted to see...

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EventsCell

    postedImages[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            myCell.postedEventImage.image = downloadedImage
        }
    }
    myCell.eventName.text = postedEvents[indexPath.row]
    myCell.eventStart.text = postedStart[indexPath.row]
    myCell.eventPrice.text = postedPrices[indexPath.row]

    return myCell
}
```

and then there is also this code on how i append to my postImages array

```
     if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {

                    self.postedImages.append(object.objectForKey("Image") as! PFFile)

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
```